# Download images returned in hash from scrapifier?

Tags: ruby, scrape

I'm trying to scrape images in a website, and download them to a local folder.

I'm using scrapifier gem which looks simple.

I've installed it, made a scrape.rb and ran it from the terminal `ruby scrape.rb`

```
require 'scrapifier'
'http://www.blog.com'.scrapify(images: :jpg)
```

This will return a hash with the info, but I would like to download the images in that info to a local folder. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
require 'scrapifier'
require 'httparty'

#This will iterate on the array of images and download them
def extract_images(arr)
    arr.each do |image_url| 
        file_name = File.basename(image_url) 
        File.open(file_name, "wb") do |f| 
            f.write HTTParty.get(image_url).parsed_response
        end
    end
end

a = 'http://www.amazon.com'.scrapify(images: :jpg)
extract_images(a[:images])
```

The above will download the photo into your current folder of execution of program

Comment: definition method should be before execution in this case.

Comment: @Зелёный, oh yeah, i placed it up with a better example of amazon which has more images. :)

Comment: I got it working with norokiri, but your solution also works. I was wondering, can I get the image dimensions? Maybe with Rmagick? I would like to download only images that are bigger than 500px

Comment: Also, that would scrape only 1 URL. I would like the program to scrape images in ALL of the paths in the website!

Comment: @Gibson, it will do for all, i am iterating on the array of images and downloading.  I tested on my local and it downloads all images returned from amazon.com

Comment: @AnkitG thanks. The thing is, sometimes, you need to click on the image to zoom it, and only downloads thumbs... Is there any way to filter that? Thanks